# Which are the possible options for pyweka multisearch function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, weka

I have this code from the examples of pyweka documentation (https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html)

```
multi = MultiSearch(options=["-sample-size", "100.0", "-initial-folds", "2", "-subsequent-folds", "2","-num-slots", "1", "-S", "1"])           
multi.evaluation = "CC"
mparam = MathParameter()
mparam.prop = "classifier.kernel.gamma"
mparam.minimum = -3.0
mparam.maximum = 3.0
mparam.step = 1.0
mparam.base = 10.0
mparam.expression = "pow(BASE,I)"
lparam = ListParameter()
lparam.prop = "classifier.C"
lparam.values = ["-2.0", "-1.0", "0.0", "1.0", "2.0"]
multi.parameters = [mparam, lparam]
cls = Classifier(
    classname="weka.classifiers.functions.SMOreg",
    options=["-K", "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel"])
multi.classifier = cls
multi.build_classifier(data)
print("Model:\n" + str(multi))
print("\nBest setup:\n" + multi.best.to_commandline())
```

And when I execute it I'm having this problem:

```
JavaException                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2021/2844706061.py in <module>
----> 1 multi = MultiSearch(options=['-sample-size', "100.0", "-initial-folds", "2", "-subsequent-folds", "2","-num-slots", "1", "-S", "1"])
      2 multi.evaluation = "CC"
      3 mparam = MathParameter()
      4 mparam.prop = "classifier.kernel.gamma"
      5 mparam.minimum = -3.0

JavaException: Illegal options: -sample-size 100.0 -initial-folds 2 -subsequent-folds 2 -num-slots 1
```

I tried to find a solution, searching what are these options but did not find anything.

Comment: documentation [shows](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/examples.html#output-help-from-underlying-optionhandler) that some objects may use `listOptions()` or `to_help()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out that error in the documentation. It should just read:

```py
multi = MultiSearch(options=["-S", "1"])
```

Just pushed out the updated documentation.

And here is a link the underlying Java class, which lists the options in its javadoc:

https://github.com/fracpete/multisearch-weka-package/blob/master/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/meta/MultiSearch.java

Comment: Any option handler in pww3 also has the `to_help()` method which you can call to generate a help screen that lists the description of the class and its command-line options.